# Ubuntu totally freezes after a few minutes

Tags: freeze, responsiveness

After months of flawless use, yesterday Ubuntu 20.04 opened until the pink screen and then nothing. As nothing was responsive I could only press the power button long enough to close, and then restart, this time I got to the normal opening screen although it took much longer than normal. A minute later the mouse froze and I discovered that nothing worked.
Doing the same thing again, I got to the point it worked a few minutes until all froze again.This time I had used to find out what to do in this case.
After once more closing the hard way I tried a few suggestions, all of them required Ubuntu and Terminal to be responsive, which it wasn't after a few minutes. Ctr+Prt Sc didn't work, Alt + F2 didn't work, Ctr + Alt + T didn't work.
So how can I get Ubuntu back to where it was. I am now using the Microsoft part of my computer and that seems to work fine.

Comment: If you can boot with a Live USB, then you may be able to access the error logs to determine why the Ubuntu installation is not behaving 

Comment: Thanks, I still have the Live USB, how would I find this error?

Comment: There may be something in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/boot.log` (or one of the `.#` files) pointing to an issue. If these logs are large (dozens or hundreds of megabytes), then there is certainly something that needs to be addressed ...

Comment: HI, thanks for your suggestion, only today did I try it out. I rebooted Ubuntu with USB inserted but did not give special command to use it, so I am not sure if Ubuntu opened using USB or normally. 
Opening the Terminal I tried your suggestions, and the terminal told me that it could not perform those tasks.
I got a prompt for updates which I did and then I needed to restart.
Now half an hour later there hasn't been a freeze yet. Could it be that the update solved my problem?